# Laravel stripe library

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments

Having problem with installing

cartalyst stripe-laravel

try to self-update to composer 
 composer update not working dnt know how to solve please help

Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

```
Problem 1
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.40
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.39
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.38
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.37
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.36
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.35
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.34
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.33
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.32
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.31
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.30
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.29
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.28
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.27
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.26
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.25
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.24
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.23
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.22
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.21
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.20
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.19
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.18
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.17
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.16
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.15
- Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v5.5.14
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.14
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.13
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.12
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.11
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.10
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.9
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.8
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.7
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.6
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.5
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.4
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.3
- Installation request for cartalyst/stripe-laravel 8.0.* -> satisfiable by cartalyst/stripe-laravel[v8.0.0].
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.2
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.1
- cartalyst/stripe-laravel v8.0.0 requires illuminate/support 5.6.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.20, v5.6.21, v5.6.22, v5.6.23, v5.6.24, v5.6.25, v5.6.26, v5.6.27, v5.6.3, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9].
- don't install illuminate/support v5.6.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.6.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
- illuminate/support v5.6.10 conflicts with laravel/framework[v5.5.0].
- illuminate/support v5.6.11 conflicts with laravel/framework[v5.5.0].
- illuminate/support v5.6.12 conflicts with laravel/framework[v5.5.0].
- illuminate/support v5.6.13 conflicts with laravel/framework[v5.5.0].
- illuminate/support v5.6.14 conflicts with laravel/framework[v5.5.0].
- illuminate/support v5.6.15 conflicts with laravel/framework[v5.5.0].
- illuminate/support v5.6.16 conflicts with laravel/framework[v5.5.0].
- illuminate/support v5.6.17 conflicts with laravel/framework[v5.5.0].
- illuminate/support v5.6.19 conflicts with laravel/framework[v5.5.0].
- don't install illuminate/support v5.6.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
- illuminate/support v5.6.20 conflicts with laravel/framework[v5.5.0].
- illuminate/support v5.6.21 conflicts with laravel/framework[v5.5.0].
- illuminate/support v5.6.22 conflicts with laravel/framework[v5.5.0].
- illuminate/support v5.6.23 conflicts with laravel/framework[v5.5.0].
- illuminate/support v5.6.24 conflicts with laravel/framework[v5.5.0].
- illuminate/support v5.6.25 conflicts with laravel/framework[v5.5.0].
- illuminate/support v5.6.26 conflicts with laravel/framework[v5.5.0].
- illuminate/support v5.6.27 conflicts with laravel/framework[v5.5.0].
- don't install illuminate/support v5.6.3|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.6.4|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.6.5|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.6.6|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.6.7|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
- illuminate/support v5.6.8 conflicts with laravel/framework[v5.5.0].
- illuminate/support v5.6.9 conflicts with laravel/framework[v5.5.0].
- Installation request for laravel/framework 5.5.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.5.0, v5.5.1, v5.5.10, v5.5.11, v5.5.12, v5.5.13, v5.5.14, v5.5.15, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.18, v5.5.19, v5.5.2, v5.5.20, v5.5.21, v5.5.22, v5.5.23, v5.5.24, v5.5.25, v5.5.26, v5.5.27, v5.5.28, v5.5.29, v5.5.3, v5.5.30, v5.5.31, v5.5.32, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.5.35, v5.5.36, v5.5.37, v5.5.38, v5.5.39, v5.5.4, v5.5.40, v5.5.5, v5.5.6, v5.5.7, v5.5.8, v5.5.9].
```

Comment: can you share your composer.json?

Answer (score 1):

It's usually good to read the readme: https://github.com/cartalyst/stripe-laravel

Version 7.0 is compatible with Laravel 5.5, Version 8.0 is compatible with Laravel 5.6.  You won't be able to use 8.0 on L5.5.